# The term "absolute geometry"

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, field-with-one-element

My question concerns the so-called absolute geometry over the "field with one element" F_1 or over the spectrum $\mathrm{Spec}(F_1)$, cf. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Borger%27s+absolute+geometry. I have heard somewhere that the term "absolute geometry" can be viewed as an analogy to noncommutative geometry:

A) If we consider a noncommutative space to be defined as the Morita equivalence class $[A]$ of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$, then the algebra of compact operators $\mathcal{K}$ is an "absolute point". Indeed, endowing the category of noncommutative spaces with the $C^{\ast}$-tensor product (the minimal tensor product), then $[A \otimes \mathcal{K}] = [A]$, since by definition, two $C^{\ast}$-algebras $A, B$ are Morita equivalent (also called strongly Morita equivalent) if and only if $A \otimes \mathcal{K} \cong B \otimes \mathcal{K}$, i.e. they are stably isomorphic.

B) Alternatively, we can view $KK$-theory as a category $\mathbf{KK}$ consisting of objects the separable $C^{\ast}$-algebras and arrows between $A$ and $B$ elements of the group $\mathrm{KK}(A, B)$. Then $\mathbf{KK}$ can be viewed as a certain kind of localization of the category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras at the absolute point $\mathcal{K}$, cf. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/KK-theory#UniversalCharacterization for more precision.

Now the questions that have been bugging me for some time after trying to understand papers of Borgers and Connes-Consani / - Marcolli:

1) In what sense is the "absolute geometry" of Borgers an analogy to the absolute geometry obtained from noncommutative spaces that I have vaguely sketched above? Is there a monoidal category $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes)$ in which the "absolute point" plays an analogous role that the compact operators play in noncommutative geometry?

2) What would an analogy of the category $\mathbf{KK}$ as a localization at the "absolute point" look like in the context of the absolute geometry of Borger?

Comment: It is true that two separable C*-algebras are strongly Morita equivalent if and only if they are stably isomorphic but, rather than the definition, this is a Theorem proved by Brown, Green and Rieffel in 1977. The definition of strong Morita equivalence is based on the existence of an imprimitivity bimodule (edited, i.e, deleted and reinstated, to correct the year of publication).